# PHP/MYSQL Update query not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, get, sql-update

Can anyone tell my why this update query is not working?

```
if ($_GET['update']) {
include 'config.php';
//Connect to MYSQL Database server
$connect = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Could not connect to MYSQL Database.");
$result = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $connect) or die("Could not connect to MYSQL table.");

mysql_query("UPDATE contact SET read = 1 WHERE id = '$_GET[update]'")or die("Query failed.");
echo "Update works!";
} else {
echo "Update does not work...ughh.";
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Edit: I got the query to work. For anyone who was worrying about the security, I was using this script as a test to see if I wanted to use it. I just added the security now that the script works. Thank you all for the help and tips.

Comment: Were not here to debug code, what error are you getting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What is column read?

```
mysql_query("UPDATE contact SET read = 1 WHERE id = '$_GET[update]'")
```

Judging by the non-capitalization of read, I suspect you are using a reserved word in MySQL for that column.

See:

[Reserved Words in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html)

To Get around this, just put a single quote around read. I.E.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE contact SET 'read' = 1 WHERE id = '$_GET[update]'")
```

Or better per j.bruni:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE contact SET `read` = 1 WHERE id = '$_GET[update]'")
```

Comment: THIS! Thanks friend! Hahah I feel so silly for using 'read'. lol Best answer.

Comment: The manual recommends "backtick" character instead of quotes.

Comment: Thanks A Ton Bro! was stuck with "match"  (Apparently a keyword ) :P

Answer (score 7):

Try this for your query line:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE contact SET read = 1 WHERE id = '".$_GET[update]."'")or die("Query failed: " . mysql_error());
```

Notice the change of the `die()` statement for better error handling:

```
die("Query failed: " . mysql_error());
```

*Also, just an FYI, you should really escape user variables (e.g. GET variables) like so to prevent SQL injections:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE contact SET read = 1 WHERE id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[update])."'")or die("Query failed: " . mysql_error());
```

Please report back the result.

Comment: +1 because OP needs to go read about sql injection right this second

Comment: I have not added the security yet!

Comment: Why code everything, then add security, that seems like a lot of work to go back and do over, why not do it right the first time?

Comment: The error is: Query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'read = 1 WHERE id = '148'' at line 1

Comment: See Nick's post below. READ is a reserved word in mysql and needs to be put in ticks `read` in your mysql statement

Comment: Merlin effort brought the error message; Nick gave the correct answer; spitfire got the credit and earned the points; we may consider it is fair, since it is his very first participation in the SO site.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to escape the string to have $_GET['update'] to add it's value to the string. But you really should be using prepared statements least you be attacked by malicious users.

Prepared Statements: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 3):

`READ` is a reserved word. You need to put it within backticks or rename your field.

Take a look at this link:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 0):

You can test so

```
mysql_query("UPDATE contact SET read = 1 WHERE id = '".(int)$_GET['update']."'")or die("Query failed.");
```

if isn't this the problem specific

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE contact SET read = 1 WHERE id = '.$_GET[update].'")or die("Query failed.");
echo "Update works!
```

Please try to not use the mysql_query. It's old and it's not efficient. why don't try to learn about the PDO and prepare statements .. ?